# IIS WebSocket Ping pong send when not idle

Tags: asp.net, iis, websocket

Background: 
I am working on learning about websockets using ASP.Net. I had a application in which I used a heartbeat to ensure that the client was still attached. In my application I would send the heartbeat every few seconds. During my reading I discovered that I could use a ping pong to achieve something similar. So after some investigation I discovered that I could configure the ping as part of IIS. During my testing though I noticed that the ping is only sent if the connection is idle not every few seconds like my heartbeat was.

Question:
Is there a way to have IIS send the every few seconds rather the only when the connection is idle? Or would my only option be to implement custom ping/pong logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is not way to change that. Configuration is limited to https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/websocket

The reason is, that there is no use for sending a PING frame when there is certainty that the connection is not idle, because the System.Net.WebSockets API does not allow you to access PING/PONG anyway. I think this is wrong because you should be able of using PING to calculate connection latency as well (since PONG will echo anything PING sent, you can use time stamps), but that is the way it is.

So yes, implementing your own PING/PONG at the application level is your only option.